# Stored procedure in console application

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, console-application

I have created console application :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NorthwindEntities nwe = new NorthwindEntities();

        var customerOrdersDetail = nwe.CustOrdersDetail(10248);

        foreach (var ordersDetail in customerOrdersDetail)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.ProductName);
            Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.UnitPrice);
            Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.Quantity);
            Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.ExtendedPrice);
            Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.Discount);
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It shows all the details about product whose ID i inputed in `nwe.CustOrdersDetail();`, but i am interested, can i input ID directly into the application when it starts? It would be more useful not to start application all over when i want to show informations about some other product.

Comment: you could write in a loop until something is encountered (or not) that just takes in IDs with a `Console.ReadLine()`  Or you could use your `string[] args` to pass in an ID at start (though this seems like it would be more difficult to "change" the ID over the first

Comment: Er... and additionally, what does this question title/tag have to do with stored procedures? :O

Comment: Because everything is connected to stored procedure called CustOrdersDetail. I did not clarify it at start, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to isolate the functionality to fetch an Order Detail item and put it into something you can call repeatedly, since this is just a console app, something like this should work to demonstrate:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FetchOrderDetail();
}

private static void FetchOrderDetail()
{
    string input = string.Empty;

    while (input != "exit")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter order detail ID: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        int orderId = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out orderId))
        {
            var customerOrdersDetail = nwe.CustOrdersDetail(orderId);

            foreach (var ordersDetail in customerOrdersDetail)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.ProductName);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.UnitPrice);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.Quantity);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.ExtendedPrice);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.Discount);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the args array and pass it on, like this:

```
var customerOrdersDetail = nwe.CustOrdersDetail(int.Parse(args[0]));
```

This way you can use it from the command line like this:

```
ConsoleApplication3 10248
ConsoleApplication3 10249
ConsoleApplication3 10250
```

Answer (score 0):

> you could write in a loop until something is encountered (or not) that just takes in IDs with a Console.ReadLine() Or you could use your string[] args to pass in an ID at start (though this seems like it would be more difficult to "change" the ID over the first

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an ID, q to quit");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();

            if (line == "q")
                break;

            int myId = int.Parse(line); // note this will throw if you enter a non int (and not q)
            OutputInformation(myId);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public static void OutputInformation(int Id)
    {
            NorthwindEntities nwe = new NorthwindEntities();

            var customerOrdersDetail = nwe.CustOrdersDetail(myId);

            foreach (var ordersDetail in customerOrdersDetail)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.ProductName);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.UnitPrice);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.Quantity);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.ExtendedPrice);
                Console.WriteLine(ordersDetail.Discount);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply enter a list of the ids you want to run through and access them from the args array:

```
foreach (var input in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(input));
}
```

Call it like this: `ConsoleApplication3 10248 10249 10250`